# Error in has.Ad(x) : object 'BRK' not found

Tags: equities, programming, portfolio

I am trying to merge a list of adjusted closes of a multitude of firms for my research on ESG, in relation to risk/reward. None of the firms seem to have a problem, except for the Berkshire Hathaway stock (BRK-A).

The code is as follows:

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

maxDate <- "2017-06-23"
minDate <- "2020-12-31" 

average <- c("BABA", "BRK-A", "V", "JNJ", "WMT", "JPM", "MA", "PG", "UNH", "DIS", "BAC", "VZ", "NKE", "NVS", "TM", "MRK", "T", "ABT", "ORCL", "ABBV", "TMO", "XOM", "ACN", "BHP", "CVX")
weights <- c(0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
getSymbols(average, from=maxDate, to=minDate)

# IMPORTANT: wait 30 seconds to let the source function finish! #
Port.prices <- na.omit(merge(Ad(BABA), Ad(BRK-A), Ad(V), Ad(JNJ), Ad(WMT), Ad(JPM), Ad(MA), Ad(PG), Ad(UNH), Ad(DIS), Ad(BAC), Ad(VZ), Ad(NKE), Ad(NVS), Ad(TM), Ad(MRK), Ad(T), Ad(ABT), Ad(ORCL), Ad(ABBV), Ad(TMO), Ad(XOM), Ad(ACN), Ad(BHP), Ad(CVX)))
Port.returns <- ROC(Port.prices, type="discrete")[-1,]
colnames(Port.returns) <- average
```

Does anyone have a (preferably simple) solution to this problem? I am still a rookie when it comes to R, so some explanation would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Philip

Comment: Try replacing BRK-A with BRKA and Ad(BRK-A) with Ad(BRKA) respectively. The lexer parser may not like the minus character.

Comment: Hello mister Rodionov, thank you for your response! Unfortunately, removing the "-" in either/both the average/getSymbols or/and merge functions did not work. However, the answer by @pleb did work and the problem is solved. Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When getting data using the quantmod package, it is a good idea to call the "Adjusted close" function `Ad()` directly on `getSymbols()`, since you **might** run into trouble otherwise (eg. loading prices into the R-environment directly, without saving it in a variable).

#### Ad-hoc solution using your own code:

As described above, you can call  `Ad()` directly on `getSymbols()` for Berkshire Hathaway stock (*BRK-A*) only. This returns the adjusted close prices, which can be saved in a variable:

```
BRK <- Ad(getSymbols("BRK-A", from = maxDate, to = minDate, auto.assign = FALSE))
```

Now, replace `Ad(BRK-A)` in `Port.prices` with `BRK` and everything should work fine. Also, setting `auto.assign = FALSE` returns the prices instead of loading them into the R-environment (see documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod/versions/0.4.18/topics/getSymbols)).

---

#### Alternative solution method:

I've taken the liberty of providing another working solution (comments provided below the code), that resembles your own code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)

maxDate <- "2017-06-23"
minDate <- "2020-12-31" 

tickers <- c("BABA", "BRK-A", "V", "JNJ", "WMT", "JPM", "MA", "PG", "UNH", "DIS", "BAC", "VZ", "NKE", "NVS", "TM", "MRK", "T", "ABT", "ORCL", "ABBV", "TMO", "XOM", "ACN", "BHP", "CVX")

n <- length(tickers)

prices <- xts()
weights <- rep(1/n, n)

for (i in 1:length(tickers)){

  getdata <- try(Ad(getSymbols(tickers[i], 
    from = maxDate, to = minDate, auto.assign = FALSE, silent = T)))

  prices <- cbind(prices, getdata)

  print(sprintf("%s", i))
}

# IMPORTANT: wait 30 seconds to let the source function finish! #
Port.returns <- ROC(prices, type="discrete")[-1,]
```

**Providing some comments on my code, in order to alleviate confusion:**

1. Your equal weight vector, `weights`, can be generalized by dividing with the number of assets, *n*, and then repeating this number *n* amount of times.
2. The library *xts*, is a multivariate time-series library and is a great tool for gathering all of your adjusted close prices into one matrix.
3. **The for loop can be explained as follows:** For each ticker in `tickers`, we get the adjusted close prices, and save them in a variable called `getdata`. We then column-bind the `getdata` variable with the prices time-series matrix. Therefore, we do not need to call `Ad()` afterwards. At first, `prices` is just an empty matrix (time-series object), so calling `cbind(prices, getdata)` will net you the first adjusted close prices for "BABA". Now, the second iteration will column-bind prices (containing "BABA" adjusted closes) and getdata (containing adjusted closes for "BRK-A"), which will effectively update the `prices` variable, now containing both "BABA" and "BRK-A" on the columns (and daily closes on the rows). This will happen until the for-loop ends, giving you a matrix `prices` containing the close prices of all assets defined by their ticker in `tickers`.

The alternative solution saves you some minutes of manually constructing the pricing matrix, `Port.prices`, and is extendable for any amount of tickers (as long as the tickers are correct). I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer and comprehensive comments! Amazing to see your alternative solution method; a LOT more streamlined than mine, quite helpful. Thank you for your time! - Philip

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix:

The Problem: For each symbol, getSymbols creates a data object in the environment by that name. Subsequent call to the data object BRK-A is interpreted by R as BRK minus A, and of course it does not find an object named BRK.

The Solution: Rename the object immediately after getSymbols call as follows. Using backticks (shift ~, not single quotes) so that interpreter takes the string in its entirety:

```
BRKA <- `BRK-A`
```

And for completeness, update your vector of symbols from BRK-A to BRKA as well so that subsequent calls to this vector look for BRKA and not BRK-A. Updated code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

maxDate <- "2017-06-23"
minDate <- "2020-12-31" 

average <- c("BABA", "BRK-A", "V", "JNJ", "WMT", "JPM", "MA", "PG", "UNH", "DIS", "BAC", "VZ", "NKE", "NVS", "TM", "MRK", "T", "ABT", "ORCL", "ABBV", "TMO", "XOM", "ACN", "BHP", "CVX")
weights <- c(0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
getSymbols(average, from=maxDate, to=minDate)
BRKA <- `BRK-A`
average <- c("BABA", "BRKA", "V", "JNJ", "WMT", "JPM", "MA", "PG", "UNH", "DIS", "BAC", "VZ", "NKE", "NVS", "TM", "MRK", "T", "ABT", "ORCL", "ABBV", "TMO", "XOM", "ACN", "BHP", "CVX")
```